# how to find out what is causing "cv::Exception at memory location"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm currently suffering from some strange exceptions that are most probably due to me doing something incorrectly while interacting with opencv:

`First-chance exception at 0x7580b9bc in xxx.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00c1c624..`

I've already enabled the `Thrown` field in the `Debug -> Exceptions` menu, however I really can't figure out where in my code the exception is thrown.

How can I debug this?

**EDIT**
the stack frame reads like this (my app won't even show up in the list!):

- KernelBase.dll!7580b8bc()
- [Frames below may be incorrect or missing ]
- KernelBase.dll!7580b8bc()
- opencv_core242d.dll!54eb60cc()

Comment: Have you stepped in with a debugger and seen what line causes the exception??

Comment: @TonyTheLion I would love to do that, but unfortunately I don't even know where in my code the exception is thrown. All I can look at is the Disassembly.

Comment: Does the exception actually terminate your program or is it handled?

Comment: If you do not catch the exception, then you just run the program in the debugger and it will automatically stop when the exception is thrown. So you don't need to know where it's thrown, the debugger will tell you.

Comment: It has an error description field: http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_exception.html what does that contain?

Comment: @Benj the exception terminates my program.

Comment: are you sure this is not just a first-chance-exception which is properly handled by the library, i.e. that it is OK? does it happen only in the debugger or does it crash your program when you run it normally?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but the debugger does not tell me where it's thrown. Or maybe I don't get it. All I want to see, is in my main program, which call to opencv is causing the problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could wrap your entire main in a try catch block which prints out the exception details.  If the open CV API can throw exceptions, you will need to think about handling them anyway as part of your design:

```
try
{
  // ... Contents of your main
}
catch ( cv::Exception & e )
{
 cerr << e.msg << endl; // output exception message
}
```

Comment: that's a start! I had to use `e.what()` instead of `e.msg()`. Now I get a least the opencv error, but still I don't know where in my program this error is caused. Is there a way to figure it out?

Comment: @memyself You should be able to figure that out by stepping through in the debugger until you suddenly end up in the catch block.  Once that happens look closely at the last Open CV function that was called from your code.

Comment: the problem is, that the program occurs randomly, and only if the user does something with the mouse. So stepping through it until the error occurs is quite elaborate. I was thinking that there should be a way to give me the line number, once the debugger is in the `catch` block - or is that not possible?

Comment: CV exceptions have various attributes: http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/classcv_1_1_exception.html can you not use this information to work out which open cv function threw the exception?

Comment: You can't actually automatically see the stack trace origin of a C++ exception when you catch it because the stack has already been unwound.  This is a common criticism of them when compared to Java/C# exceptions where you can.

Comment: if I move the `try/catch` into my sub-function, then I might be able to find the line, correct?

Comment: @memyself Correct, you might get some milage from temporarily putting try/catch everywhere and seeing which one catches.

Answer (score 5):

OpenCV has this handy function called [cv::setBreakOnError](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gae4904ef072dede53cf161d9a6869083f&gsc.tab=0)

If you put the following into your main before any opencv calls:

```
cv::setBreakOnError(true);
```

then your program will crash, because OpenCV will do an invalid operation (dereferencing a null pointer) just before it would throw cv::Exception normally. If you run your code in a debugger, it will stop at this illegal operation, and you can see the whole call stack with all of your codes and variables at the time of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve got this problem by using OpenCV with WebCam. The problem in my case is that the program is trying to read an image when the Cam hasn't been initialized.

my error code:

```
 // open camera
capture.open(0);
while (1){
    //store image to matrix // here is the bug
    capture.read(cameraFeed);
```

The solution

```
 // open camera
capture.open(0);
while (1){

     //this line makes the program wait for an image 
     while (!capture.read(cameraFeed));

    //store image to matrix 
    capture.read(cameraFeed);
```

(sorry about my english)
Thanks