# circle hough center co-ordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

In `opencv`, I am using Hough transform for circle finder here is the code

```
HoughCircles (diff, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, src.cols / 5, 200, 80, 20, 62);    

for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
{
    //if(circles[i][2]<62)
    {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // draw the green circle center
        circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
        // draw the blue circle outline
        circle(src, center, radius, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes in case it found 3 circles, the third one center coordinates are fraction not integer as supposed to be also in case it found 4 circles it give this error

> Unhandled exception at 0x75ebc41f in xyz.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
>   cv::Exception at memory location 0x002df08c..

if I tried to `cout` the center co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm this is interesting. I ran your code and filled-in the before and after and didn't have any problems. To be honest, I've only tested on a linux and mac machine. Here is my full length code, try that and see what happens. Also, check this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687684/how-to-find-out-what-is-causing-cvexception-at-memory-location).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

VideoCapture capture(0);
if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    LOG(FATAL) << "COULD NOT OPEN CAPTURE";
}

Mat frame;
capture >> frame;
if (frame.empty()) {
    LOG(FATAL) << "FRAME IS EMPTY!";
}

char key;
while ((int)key != 27) {

    capture >> frame;

    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray.cols/5,200,80,20,62);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i) {
        Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // draw the green circle center
        circle(frame, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
        // draw the blue circle outline
        circle(frame, center, radius, Scalar(0,255,0), 3, 8, 0 );
    }

    imshow("frame", frame);
    key = waitKey(1);
}

return 0;
}
```