# OpenCV Unhandled Exception when calling readNet() C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv

I'm trying to load a tensorflow model as so:

```
String model = "model.pb";
CV_Assert(!model.empty());
Net net = readNet(model);
```

and keep running into this error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF24A54F99 in OpenCVTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000005C0495D8B0.
```

I'm new to opencv and the mistake is not glaringly obvious to me.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/12688215/2482068